# How to compile Vim with GUI?

Tags: vim, ruby, compiling

I want to learn how to compile vim from the sources, because there are some additions that I want to add, and learn how to deal with this situations, but until now I didn't have success doing it, I can compile vim, but without its GUI

I think it's a dependencies problem, but I can't figure out which packages I have to install, what are the dependencies to compile vim with its gui?

I found an article about [how to compile gvim](http://aufather.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/building-gvim/), but I don't have the packages for install in my ubuntu 10.10 repositories, I hope to find some help with this

Greetings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally you can use the "build-dep" command of "apt-get" to fetch dependencies to a package. Use it like this:

> sudo apt-get build-dep [package name]

Or more specifically for gvim:

> sudo apt-get build-dep vim-gnome

After that you should be able to compile gvim/vim either without further intervention or with only small set of dependencies to resolve required by a newer version of gvim/vim that you are compiling.

As Marius noted one such dependency resolution is installing libssl-dev manually:

> sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

Enjoy!

Comment: I just found this solution on the vim's mailing list, that was I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: There's no package `gvim`.  You want `sudo apt-get build-dep vim-gnome`.

Comment: One thing I also discovered when building newest vim versions on Ubuntu lucid: you also need to install `libssl-dev` explicitly, as it was not a build dependency for the version of vim packaged in Ubuntu at the time.

Answer (score 0):

For building Vim on Ubuntu or Debian, follow the steps listed here: https://gist.github.com/211238